# Failover DNS When Primary Can't Resolve?

Tags: dns

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop workstation on a network that hosts a Windows domain.  The Windows domain servers provide DNS resolution for local servers, but don't always provide accurate DNS resolution for remote servers.  This means that, if I make a non-domain DNS server as my primary (such as Google's 8.8.8.8), I can resolve web servers but not local servers.  If I put the domain controller as my primary DNS server, I can resolve local servers, but not some web servers (notably AWS Cloudfront endpoints).

Example with Google DNS as primary and domain controller as secondary:

```
nslookup localserver
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find localserver: NXDOMAIN
```

Is there a way to get DNS resolution to check with the secondary DNS server in the event that the primary DNS server is unable to resolve a DNS name?

Comment: you should setup a forwarder on your windows dns server

Comment: If I understand you right, than you are trying something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109115/combining-different-dns-servers And than the given solution is also for you

Answer (score 0):

You can see your current configured DNS server list in

```
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

If it does not contain all the DNS server you need, try adding more, each separated by comma in the network settings under IPV4 tab, [IPV4 DNS setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmbDh.png)

If that doesn't work, you can setup fallback DNS directly in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

Here's a sample:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

Comment: Thank-you for your reply.  I edited the DNS servers in network settings, and that changed what's in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, but the problem persists.  Un-commenting and filling in the lines in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf don't seem to have had any effect.  Is there a way to verify that the latter file is being read?

Comment: Try looking at /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

I just learned that you now can use this command: systemd-resolve --status